# Which are the magic system of YGGDRASIL?

Tags: overlord

Acording to [Magic Caster](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Caster) link from the Overlord wiki:

> All tier spells in YGGDRASIL could be categorized in **four great systems** of magic, each one with some exclusive spells and characteristics; **at the same way, magic casters are categorized** by the system of magic that they use. Magic role players gain access to this systems through specific job classes like:
>   (...)

That means that **magic casters** are one of the four magic systems in YGGDRASIL. I'm looking for the another three... Which are?

I've seen the first, second and now seeing the third season of the anime, but I don't have any problem if you need to make a spoiler of the novel or manga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the quote on the [wiki](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Caster#Introduction_to_Types_of_Magic_Casters). Since the creation of this question, the wiki quote has actually changed, however.

> All tier spells in YGGDRASIL could be categorized into **four great systems of magic**, each one with some exclusive spells and characteristics. **Not only that, but magic casters too are also categorized** by the system of magic that they use. (emphasis yours)

I believe this simply means that tier magic is categorized into 4 systems of magic: Arcane, Divine, Spiritual, and Alternative. In the same way, magic casters are categorized by the 4 systems of magic. Arcane Magic Caster, Divine Magic Caster, Spiritual Magic Caster, and Alternative Magic Caster.

> Arcane Type Magic Caster: Elementalist, Sorcerer, etc. 
> Divine Type Magic Caster: Cleric, Hierophant, etc. 
> Spiritual Type Magic Caster: Talisman User, Shaman, etc.
>
> There are other categories like Blessing type, that belong to the Alternative system: 
> Blessing Type Magic Caster: Bard, Paladin, Cursed Knight, etc.

## Edit

[Runecraft](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Runecraft) and [Wild Magic](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Magic) are completely different forms of magic from [Tier Magic](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Tier_Magic). Magic casters in the New World are practitioners of Tier Magic.

> All **tier** spells in YGGDRASIL could be categorized into four great systems of magic. (emphasis mine)

Runecraft and Wild Magic were forms of magic that were created LONG before the introduction of Tier Magic. These forms of magic were limited to specific races, and are now very rare in the New World.

Comment: But, there are also magical runes. So wouldn't be Magic caster a type of magic, runes another, and then there are another 2 magic types which we still don't know? Or that classification that I'm talking about with 4 magic types doesn't exist (In YGGDRASIL runes doesn't exist)? English isn't my main language so maybe I've just misunderstood it... What do you think?

Comment: No, you've misunderstood it. Magical runes, along with wild magic, are completely separate and different from tier magic. `All TIER spells in YGGDRASIL could be categorized into four great systems of magic.` Tier magic is categorized into the four types, Arcane, Divine, Spiritual, and Alternative. And magic casters are categorized into which of the four types they primarily used. Runecraft and Wild Magic were completely different magical arts that were created a long time ago before tier magic, and there are very very few runecraft and wild magic practitioners left in the New World.

Answer (score 0):

No spoilers, perhaps I even misunderstood the question, but here are the 4 types:

- Arcane: these are simply elemental magic like Lightning and such
- Divine: these are healing type magic that can be used to heal themselves or their allies
- Spiritual: these contain abstract magic
- Alternative: as the name implies, these are every other magic

Comment: Sorry, but that four types (Arcane, Divine, Spiritual and Alternative (AKA: blessed)) are subcategories of Magic Casters.

Comment: Oh ok. I, I read the question again and realized I misunderstood your question. It wasn’t the four categories of magic caster but the four categories which magic caster lies in. Sorry for that